# retrieve the last 5 entries in database php pdo

Tags: php, html, pdo

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM events ORDER by event_id DESC LIMIT 5") ;
        $stmt->bindValue(1,$eventwhat);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            while($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $_SESSION['id'] = $selected_row['event_id'];
                $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'] = $selected_row['event_what'];
                $_SESSION['searchresultwhere'] = $selected_row['event_where'];
                $_SESSION['searchresultwhen'] = $selected_row['event_when'];
                $_SESSION['searchresultwho'] = $selected_row['event_who'];
                echo $_SESSION['id']."\r\n";
                echo $_SESSION['searchresultwhat']."\r\n";
                echo $_SESSION['searchresultwhere']."\r\n";
                echo $_SESSION['searchresultwhen']."\r\n";
                echo $_SESSION['searchresultwho']."\r\n";
                echo "<br/>\n";
            }
        }
```

i have the code above to echo the last 5 entries in my database but the problem is it only show 4 it does not get the last 5 so when i have i entry only it does not show anything..what am i missing here why is the last entry not being retrieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove if condition and do like below

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM events ORDER by event_id DESC LIMIT 5") ;
$stmt->bindValue(1,$eventwhat);
$stmt->execute();

while($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $selected_row['event_id'];
    $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'] = $selected_row['event_what'];
    $_SESSION['searchresultwhere'] = $selected_row['event_where'];
    $_SESSION['searchresultwhen'] = $selected_row['event_when'];
    $_SESSION['searchresultwho'] = $selected_row['event_who'];
    echo $_SESSION['id']."\r\n";
    echo $_SESSION['searchresultwhat']."\r\n";
    echo $_SESSION['searchresultwhere']."\r\n";
    echo $_SESSION['searchresultwhen']."\r\n";
    echo $_SESSION['searchresultwho']."\r\n";
    echo "<br/>\n";
}
```

Your if condition fetaches first row and so while will fetch remaining 4 rows

Comment: cant accept yet need to wait a few more minutes..in the mean time i want to ask why it behave like that i want to fully understand why

Comment: because every time when you execute line `$selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` it get a row. you are using first in if so in while you will receive only remaining 4 rows

Comment: thank you sir for explaining happy coding will accept the answer in a few minutes still cant accept it

Answer (score -1):

```
function makeGetRequest(e, key) {
if (!e) e = window.event;

if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.button == 1) { //this is to be able to open links by clicking the wheel button or ctrl+click
    http.open('GET', key, true);
    //assign a handler for the response
    http.onreadystatechange = processResponse;
    //actually send the request to the server
    http.send(null);

    return false; //this is important, otherwise the href link will trigger and not the onclick 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe, what you are suggesting?

Comment: This seems to have no bearing on the question asked.